# How to obtain sum of a column from multiple rows with a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get the sum of multiple values of a column in a single row with LEFT JOIN.

Here are the tables

```
CREATE TABLE stocks
(
    id text NOT NULL,
    quantity bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1

);

CREATE TABLE transfers
(
    stock_id text NOT NULL,
    quantity bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1

);
```

Here is my query at the moment,

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT stocks.id,
          stocks.quantity,
          transfers.quantity AS tquantity,
          stocks.quantity - transfers.quantity AS remaining
   FROM stocks
   LEFT JOIN transfers ON transfers.stock_id = stocks.id) AS stocks
WHERE remaining > 0
  OR remaining IS NULL;
```

Which returns the following result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGvr1.png)

How can I sum the `tquantity` of the rows with `id1` and subtract that from the stocks.quantity and show them as a single row instead of 2 separate rows?

So instead of this:
[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT11H.png)

I need this:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLxKl.png)

Here is the dbfiddle, so you can see the data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b448128cb7e2fc692c023be379d165d9

How can I achieve this desired result optimally?

Comment: If you're question is about PostgreSQL, then don't add the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
 SELECT stocks.id,
        stocks.quantity,
        sum(transfers.quantity) as tquantity,
        (stocks.quantity - coalesce(sum(transfers.quantity),0)) as remaining 
 FROM stocks
 LEFT JOIN transfers ON transfers.stock_id = stocks.id
 group by stocks.id, stocks.quantity
HAVING (stocks.quantity - coalesce(sum(transfers.quantity),0))  > 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed. I will read about using `group by` effectively.

Comment: if you're new into sql take a look to window functions too ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,quantity, sum(tquantity), count(remaining)      FROM (select stocks.id, stocks.quantity, transfers.quantity AS tquantity,
stocks.quantity - transfers.quantity as remaining FROM stocks
LEFT JOIN transfers on transfers.stock_id = stocks.id) AS stocks
WHERE remaining > 0 OR remaining is null
group by id,quantity
order by id asc
 ;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0aa4001cd418853290b4dc3cba8c0754)

Comment: Thank you, I needed the sum of the values of the remaining columns instead of the count but this is very helpful.